# How to install .Net 4.5 Framework in Windows 2022 Docker?

Tags: .net, windows, docker

I am trying to install .Net Framework 4.5 in a Windows 2022 (required by my organization) Docker Image.

The .NET framework (looks like) get installed but I cannot find it in the system.

This is what I have got so far

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command"]

RUN New-Item -Path 'C:\helpers' -ItemType Directory;

# https://blog.hildenco.com/2020/01/determining-installed-net-framework.html
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/hd9/powershell/raw/master/list-dotnet-frameworks.ps1 -OutFile C:\helpers\list-dotnet-frameworks.ps1;

RUN C:\helpers\list-dotnet-frameworks.ps1

# Download and install .Net v4.5 Framework
RUN $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
    $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; \
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'; \
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/A/4/BA4A7E71-2906-4B2D-A0E1-80CF16844F5F/dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe" -OutFile "$env:TEMP\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe" -UseBasicParsing; \
    $p = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -FilePath "$env:TEMP\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/q","/norestart"; \
    rm "$env:TEMP\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe"

RUN C:\helpers\list-dotnet-frameworks.ps1
```

I was hoping that the output of the script `C:\helpers\list-dotnet-frameworks.ps1` running in the second time would should up .Net Framework 4.5 but the out put has been same as below.

```
Installed .Net Framework 4.0c
Installed .Net Framework 4.0
Installed .Net Framework 4.7.2
```

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 has been unsupported since January 2016. That was over 7 years ago. Please upgrade if you want to avoid all kinds of security holes. Windows Server 2022 comes preinstalled with .NET Framework 4.8. You won't be able to install 4.5 without first uninstalling 4.8 and that may be a very difficult task, especially in a container.